# jQuery show only 5 list items of multiple unordered lists

Tags: jquery, show-hide

First of all I am new to jQuery/JS so thank you for your help in advance. Many days I've been trying to find a solution to the following problem:
I have a list , which is made from **multiple unordered lists** with there own items. What I want is show only the first 5 list items of all UL items and only if the "load more" link is clicked, the rest of the list items should be displayed. See printscreen for clarification:
http://i61.tinypic.com/swabnq.jpg 
I know how to do this with one UL, but not with the multiple.

I have already have the following piece of code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="category-overview">
    <div class="content-title">
        <h3 class="pull-left">Our products</h3>
        <span class="pull-right">
            <a href="#" class="title-toggle-control"></a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="grey-divider"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="category-overview-list">
            <h4>Title1</h4>
            <ul class="list">
                <li><a href="#">List item 01</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 02</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 03</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 04</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 05</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 06</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 07</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="category-overview-list">
            <h4>Title2</h4>
            <ul class="list">
                <li><a href="#">List item 01</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 02</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 03</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 04</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 05</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 06</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 07</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        etc...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

And JS code:

```
$('.category-overview-list ul').each(function (i) {
    var ul = $(this),
        l = ul.children('li'),
        h = l.height();
    ul.css({ 'height': (h * 5) + 'px', 'overflow': 'hidden' });
    $(this).siblings('.control').addClass('closed');
    $(this).siblings('.control').html('<a href="#">show more <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>');
});
$('.control').click(function () {
    var ul = $(this).parent().children("ul"),
        l = ul.children('li'),
        h = l.height();
    var me = $(this);
    if (me.is('.closed')) {
        ul.parent().children("ul").animate({
            'height': (ul.height() > (h * 5) ?
            (h * 5) : (l.length * h)) + 'px'
        });
        me.removeClass('closed');
        me.addClass('open');
        $(this).html('<a href="#">show less <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>');
    } else {
        //ul.css({'height':(h*3)+'px','overflow':'hidden'});
        ul.animate({ 'height': (h * 5) + 'px', 'overflow': 'hidden' });
        me.removeClass('open');
        me.addClass('closed');
        $(this).html('<a href="#">show more <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>');
    }
    return false;
});
```

I really hope someone can help me out with this one.

Comment: Whats the issue with above code ? if possible create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: This is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/justamir/Xhn5h/ whit the same principle but now I want to achieve the same with multiple UL

Comment: IS this what you wanted ? http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Xhn5h/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uM2jG/31/)

Added default height with css, and on click I am running jquery to get all ul tags and increase the height.

I am not using any of your javascript code, I don't know if they clash or if you are using it elsewhere

```
$('#show_more').click(function() {
    $(".category-overview" ).find( "ul" ).height(100);
});
```

[**New fiddle here with dynamic height**](http://jsfiddle.net/uM2jG/48/)
**EDIT:** changed it to work with %. eg. first ul has 9 elements => longer => show all 9!

Comment: This does work but it works on the basis of height. And this is not how it should be. Anyway thanks for the effort.

Comment: You can get the height of each li element, and make it x2 to show 2 elements, x3 for 3 etc.

Comment: @amir edited my answer to hopefully a more suitable solution, also added a toggle functionality

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and effort. It works like a charm. Thanks to people like you we as beginners learn a lot. There is only one thing. Everytime i click on show more/less the hidden items are visible for just a short moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avGZt/3/

The solution I used is as follows:

You might try hiding the LIs with CSS, like so:

```
/* It's n+6 because it starts at 1, rather than 0 */
.closed ul.list li:nth-child(n+6) {
    display: none;
}
```

Then to show them, have the handler apply a class to the parent of all the ULs:

```
$('.control').click(function () {
    $('.category-overview').toggleClass('closed');
});
```

You don't need two separate classes, it's a bit overkill and it's much easier to just toggle. You can also have the "show more" button change with CSS as well, like so:

```
.closed .control.less { display: none; }
.closed .control.more { display: block; }
.control.more { display: none; }
```

Of course, that assumes that you create two "show more/less" buttons.

Now, this might not be the prettiest solution, it could use some refining but I think you'll find it's a much cleaner approach than trying to force it all to happen with javascript.

Comment: This works but the "show more" link opens items from the first UL. And what I want is to open all hidden list items from all UL

Comment: Ohh, just one single button for all of them? Easy enough, let me update.

Comment: @Amir Okay so I updated it so that the show more/less buttons show/hide ALL of the extra items at once. I apply the class to the parent container, and that 'closed' class applies to the LIs as well as the show more/less buttons so you can do it all in one place :)

Comment: thanks for your solution. I've never thought this could be done with some small of JS and CSS.

Comment: Thanks! If you find that you are writing an event handler in jQuery and it's growing to mammoth proportions, see if there's some CSS that will accomplish some or part of it. It is actually surprising how much it can simplify things, just be aware of browser support. (In this case, nth-child is decently well supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child )

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a class for any elements to show/hide them.  What I would do is add a class in your  element with

```
.hide{display:none}
```

Then, when you first load your page, any element in the list that is over 5, you should add the *hide* class:

```
<div class="category-overview-list">
        <h4>Title1</h4>
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="#">List item 01</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List item 02</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List item 03</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List item 04</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List item 05</a></li>
            <li class="hide"><a href="#">List item 06</a></li>
        <li class="hide"><a href="#">List item 07</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, when you click your control button, your code should look something like:

```
$('.control').click(function () {
    var ul = $(this).parent().children("ul"),
    var me = $(this);
    if (me.is('.closed')) {
        me.removeClass('closed hide');
        me.addClass('open');
        $(this).html('<a href="#">show less <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>');
    } else {
        me.addClass('closed hide').removeClass('open');
        $(this).html('<a href="#">show more <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>');
    }
return false;
});
```

Comment: You give to the last LI items the class "hide", but this should be done dynamicly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.list').each(function(){
        var liLength = $(this).find('li').length;
        var max = 6;        
        if (liLength > max) { 
          $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide();
           $(this).parent().append($('<li class="addMoreList">load more</li>').click(function(){ 
                $(this).siblings('li:hidden').show();
            })
          );

        }

    });
```

Comment: yes I've tried this with jsfidle but it's not working. Can you try this code with jsfidle?